# Can't redefine CKFinder plugins directory

Tags: symfony, yaml, ckfinder

I'm testing CKFinder with 'ckfinder-symfony-bundle' in a Symfony 4 project.

I would like to move the default folder 'public/bundles/fosckeditor/plugins' in to my project folder like 'src/EventSubscriber'. It's for making a plugin class and versionning it.

According to the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_pluginsDirectory) it's possible...

But I have an error when I check with URI '.../ckfinder/connector?command=Init' :

```
Unrecognized option "pluginsDirectory" under "ckfinder.connector". Available options are "accessControl", ... "plugins", ... "xSendfile".
```

And no pluginsDirectory option in these options... :(

I'm using a Yaml config file :

```
ckfinder:
  connector:
   ...
  backends:
   ...
  resourceTypes:
   ...
  accessControl:
   ...
  pluginsDirectory: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/EventSubscriber'
  plugins:
  - myFuturPlugin
```

What I'm doing wrong or not ? Thanks for your help.

EDIT1:

The 'pluginsDirectory' node is missing in 'vendor/ckfinder/ckfinder-symfony-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php' :

```
...
->arrayNode('plugins')
    ->prototype('variable')->end()
->end()

->scalarNode('pluginsDirectory')->end() //Here ! :)

->arrayNode('cache')
...
```

EDIT2:

So I found/make some modifications in 'vendor/ckfinder/ckfinder-symfony-bundle/_connector/CKFinder.php

```
...
$pluginPath = Path::combine($pluginsDirectory, $pluginName, $pluginName . '.php');

if (file_exists($pluginPath) && is_readable($pluginPath)) {
    require_once $pluginPath;
    //New namespace from the pluginsDirectory redefine folder
    foreach (get_declared_classes() as $name) {
        $pos = strpos($name, $pluginName);
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $pluginClassName = substr($name, 0, $pos) . $pluginName . '\\' . $pluginName;
        }
    }
} else {
    //Default namespace from CKFinder
    $pluginClassName = CKFinder::PLUGINS_NAMESPACE . $pluginName . '\\' . $pluginName;
}

if (!class_exists($pluginClassName)) {
    throw new InvalidPluginException(sprintf('CKFinder plugin "%s" not found (%s)', $pluginName, $pluginClassName), array('pluginName' => $pluginName));
}
...
```

Comment: Now I have to find solution for registering the new URL in 'vendor/ckfinder/ckfinder-symfony-bundle/_connector/CKFinder.php. , in method registerPlugins().

Because the namespace is not in the good place : 

$pluginClassName = CKFinder::PLUGINS_NAMESPACE . $pluginName . '\\' . $pluginName;

Comment: I will open a issue for this in GitHub : https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-symfony-bundle

Comment: Nothing append to this issue from August 2020... :(